Why do I get an UnidentifiedImageError error when doing step 4 of Build a Q&A App with Multi-Modal RAG using Gemini Pro tutorial?
Hi I'm trying to follow the tutorial "Build a Q&A App with Multi-Modal RAG using Gemini Pro" at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/multimodal-rag-gemini#6.
I've ran all the code from the pip installs to all the code in Step 4. (Generating Image Summaries)
This supposedly would give me summaries for the images in the cj folder. The base64 and dataUri for the image are all valid and generate a proper image.
So why would PIL give me an UnidentifiedImageError?
Here's the code I ran
import base64
import os

from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage

def encode_image(image_path):
   """Getting the base64 string"""
   with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
       return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode("utf-8")


def image_summarize(img_base64, prompt):
   """Make image summary"""
   model = ChatVertexAI(model_name="gemini-pro-vision", max_output_tokens=1024)
   print(f"Base64 for image: {img_base64}")
   data_url =  f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{img_base64}"
   print(f"data url for image: {data_url}")

   msg = model(
       [
           HumanMessage(
               content=[
                   {"type": "text", "text": prompt},
                   {
                       "type": "image_url",
                       "image_url": {"url": data_url},
                   },
               ]
           )
       ]
   )
   return msg.content


def generate_img_summaries(path):
   """
   Generate summaries and base64 encoded strings for images
   path: Path to list of .jpg files extracted by Unstructured
   """

   # Store base64 encoded images
   img_base64_list = []

   # Store image summaries
   image_summaries = []

   # Prompt
   prompt = """You are an assistant tasked with summarizing images for retrieval. \
   These summaries will be embedded and used to retrieve the raw image. \
   Give a concise summary of the image that is well optimized for retrieval."""

   # Apply to images
   for img_file in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
       if img_file.endswith(".jpg"):
           img_path = os.path.join(path, img_file)
           base64_image = encode_image(img_path)
           img_base64_list.append(base64_image)
           print(f"Processing image: {img_path}")
           image_summaries.append(image_summarize(base64_image, prompt))

   return img_base64_list, image_summaries


# Image summaries
img_base64_list, image_summaries = generate_img_summaries("./cj")

len(img_base64_list)

len(image_summaries)

image_summaries[0]



Here are the debugging logs
Processing image: ./cj/figure-10-1.jpg
Base64 for image: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8U...
data url for image: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyP...
<ipython-input-10-7bd9e56019eb>:14: LangChainDeprecationWarning: The method `BaseChatModel.__call__` was deprecated in langchain-core 0.1.7 and will be removed in 1.0. Use invoke instead.
  msg = model(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7bd9e56019eb> in <cell line: 60>()
     58 
     59 # Image summaries
---> 60 img_base64_list, image_summaries = generate_img_summaries("./cj")
     61 
     62 len(img_base64_list)

18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3281             raise TypeError(msg) from e
   3282     else:
-> 3283         rawmode = mode
   3284     if mode in ["1", "L", "I", "P", "F"]:
   3285         ndmax = 2

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ed3d80c19e0>

The cj folder is filled up and figure-10-1.jpg is a chart when opened. 

@DarkBee I have now edited the question  to give more context. The relevant code and debugging logs are now in a code block.
